# How to insert a standalone Back navigation button into my Windows application?

Tags: windows, winapi, button, navigation, win32gui

I want to use the same button in my own dialog:

[image: I want this button]

As I can see, it is used by Windows Explorer and some other system dialogs.

Is it a standard control? How can I insert it into my application?

Comment: That button is provided by the Aero Wizard framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is provided by visual styles (UXTHEME.DLL).

However you must do it yourself. Owner-draw or subclassed button which will paint it using OpenThemeData (class is "NAVIGATION"), part NAV_BACKBUTTON.

Note that as always with UXTHEME.DLL you should also have a fallback if UXTHEME.DLL is not available (before XP), is disabled or if the class "NAVIGATION" is not defined (it is only added in Aero, XP's Luna does not have it).